# Mobile image margin issue

Tags: html, blogger, margins

I am working on a blog design and am having difficulty with the mobile view, when you click on a post or "read more" (on your phone) the images go from center to right aligned. I need to find out how to keep them center. Further is there anyway to fully justify the text.

http://smittenpremadempom.blogspot.com/

Thanks so much,
Christine

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to center images in mobile device to have a responsive design](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35107162/how-to-center-images-in-mobile-device-to-have-a-responsive-design)

Answer (score 1):

change the position of the images to absolute, see if that works

Comment: Hmm, thanks but that didn't seem to help. Any other thoughts?